# how to render and dump the file sls with salt stack without applying it

Tags: render, state, salt-stack

Given how flexible jinja templating can be with saltstack and the numerous pillar variables are merged into the template; I would find it useful to be able to get salt to 'render' the full sls out to screen before i push it out. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just to answer my own question: I knew that [`state.show_top`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.show_top) existed. So I tried [`state.show_sls`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.show_sls), and voila! Exactly what I'm after.