# How to use salt to test out jinja functionality?

Tags: command-line, salt-stack

I am looking for a way to test if salt would render a jinja template the way I expect it to.

If I have a file `template.sls` containing:

```
{% for usr in ['moe','larry','curly'] %}
{{ usr }}:
  user.present
{% endfor %}
```

Can I run a salt command that will show me the rendered template?

NB: I understand that what's happening is Jinja doing the rendering, and I can template it in python. But I want to ensure that I am using the Jinja version used by salt. AFAIK salt embeds the jinja engine.

An example of what I am looking for is a salt command that would function similarly to the following ansible command:

**The following was taken from accepted answer to:** [How can I test jinja2 templates in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407822/how-can-i-test-jinja2-templates-in-ansible/35407823#35407823)

**3_Ansible** (using --check)

Create test playbook jinja2test.yml:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: Test jinja2template
    template: src=test.j2 dest=test.conf
```

and run it:

```
ansible-playbook jinja2test.yml --check --diff --connection=local
```

sample output:

```
PLAY [127.0.0.1] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************

ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK: [Test jinja2template] ***************************************************
--- before: test.conf
+++ after: /Users/user/ansible/test.j2
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+Mike
+Smith
+Klara
+Alex

changed: [127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display the resulting SLS you can use the [slsutil.renderer](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.slsutil.html#salt.modules.slsutil.renderer)

It's quite easy, and should do the trick.
In my case I'm using it like this:

`salt 'test01' slsutil.renderer salt://blabla/test.sls 'jinja|yaml'`

Answer (score 2):

Best and simplest way is to use state.show_sls as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191710/how-to-render-and-dump-the-file-sls-with-salt-stack-without-applying-it)

Please check the official doc [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.show_sls)

For your specific case that would be something along this :

```
salt "your_minion" state.show_sls template.sls
```